# Conceptual question about Magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am confused about Magnetic force whether it does work or NOT because i think that the battery does the word and the magnetic force only redirects the work done by battery into some displacement etc. but somewhere i read that work done by magnetic force is taken into account . so I want to ask whether it does some work or not???

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Harsh Jha!  Before I consider taking the time to write an answer, would you please (1) peruse the [Q & A here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=work+magnetic+force) related to work and magnetic force and then (2) edit your post to explicitly state what in your question isn't addressed in the existing Q & A?

Comment: i checked all those question asked on that page but what i found out was just controversies someone is saying it does but someone is saying it does not and no one is mentioning anything about battery doing any work. please help me out?? @AlfredCentauri